# How to install boost::contract?

Tags: c++, boost, installation

I want to install [boost::contract](https://github.com/boostorg/contract) on my computer. There're a lot of documents except how to install it. I googled it and I also visited boost.org to find how to install it, but it is not documented.

I'm using Debian 9.4 amd64 version and I have gcc-6.3, clang-5.0, clang-6.0 installed on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just install Boost: https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_67_0.html.

You do not use the distro supplied version because that's too old (Boost Contract is a new library in 1.67.0).

Then you build boost following their guide https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/more/getting_started/index.html

And you use Boost Contract as described here https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/contract/doc/html/boost_contract/getting_started.html